# Map All Characters to Actions using KeyBindings

Tags: java, swing, key, key-bindings, keystroke

I am not new to the use of Swing, but I do a heavy amount of work with it, and I'm designing a new application. It is a drawing application. It will allow the user to click at certain places in a blank white "viewer" window, type letters and symbols using their keyboard, and thus edit the text somewhere on their viewer window.

Since I'm not using the `JComponent` to display this text, I need a reliable way for my application to accept input. I have chosen to use KeyBindings. But my special viewer component begins with an empty input map and empty action map.

My question. What's the simplest way to map all the letters and *symbols* that I can type using my keyboard to `AbstractAction`'s using the ActionMap and InputMap? The action map needs to use `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` to catch all input to the interface.

**EDIT:** 
I used to use a keylistener in order to do this but I failed at getting modularity the 
way I wanted to

I trashed the code. Threw it away completely. What I believe it said was this in SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;

public class MyKeysHandler extends KeyListener {
//blah blah blah
//blah blah blah
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke)
{
// please excuse if the boolean logic of my use of masks is off
// their proper use doesn't come to me easily
// I hope you can get the jist
    if((ke.getModifiersEx() & KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK) != 0) { 
        switch(ke.getKeyCode()) {
            // handle capital letters
        case VK_DELETE      : editor.handleThisSpecialKey(ke.getKeyCode);   
        case VK_BACK_SLASH  : // handle back slash
        case VK_7       : // handle the ampersand
        case VK_8       : // handle the asterisk character
        default         : // if just a normal letter...
            editor.handleThisNormalKeyPlease(KeyEvent.getKeyText(ke.getKeyCode()).toUpperCase());
        }
    }
    else {
        switch(ke.getKeyCode()) {
        case VK_DELETE      : // handle the shift-delete command
        case VK_BACK_SLASH  : // handle the question mark
        case VK_7       : // handle the 7
        case VK_8       : // handle the 8
        defualt :
            if(ke.getKeyCode() == VK_C && ke.getModifiersEX() & KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK) != 0) {
                editor.handleTheCopyCommandPlease();    
            }   
            else 
                editor.handleThisKeyPlease(KeyEvent.getKeyText(ke.getKeyCode).toLowerCase());
        }
    }       
}
}
```

But this got really REALLY cumbersome. Every time you add a key you have to make sure it doesn't conflict with some other key code in the same method, and for every single keylistener you have to make for any application you have to include this meticulous "VK" switch code.

My application will also have menus, and I want to install new keybindings or accelerators (or whatever they're called - mnemonics?) for those too when I have the time. For moving text around, and for deleting them, it might just be nice to have just a few special key combos that do this. As far as key combos in what you see above? You can imagine how much of a nightmare that became for me.

I assure you without posting more code, that I try to follow good models of good reusable computer programming practice. I have a model that runs below and actually handles the editing, and a view that runs above and handles the menu button code.

Unfortunately I wish Java didn't have to be so cumbersome as what is shown above. Not all but most of my keys on my keyboard need a different response depending on what key you pressed, and combos like ctrl and shift are supported in KeyBindings.

My hope is that there is a loop solution. Then again maybe there is a solution that uses `WHEN-IN-ANCESTOR` and would also work. The input map I'm using is the components root pane, but I'm also open to going as far down as the viewer component itself (A JPanel) and get its `InputMap` instance, but I haven't done so yet because I'm experimenting.

The way that I currently access items is this: This works well for me. But it doesn't handle symbols. Maybe if I increased the span of characters in the for loop? Or manually add a few? I don't know.

```
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
public void initKeyBindingsTheEasyWay() {

JRootPane rootPane = mainPane.getRootPane();
InputMap theWIMap = rootPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
ActionMap theAMap = rootPane.getActionMap();
for(char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
    // lower case   
    KeyStroke little = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed " + c);
    theWIMap.put(little, ""+Character.toLowerCase(c));
    theAMap.put(""+Character.toLowerCase(c), new LetterAction(Character.toLowerCase(c)));
}
}

public static class LetterAction extends AbstractAction
{
    char theLetter;
    public LetterAction(char letter)
    {
        theLetter = letter;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        System.out.print(theLetter);
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't really what key bindings are really good for. If you must have a gloabl level key listener, you could consider using an AWTListener instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer See my edit above.

Comment: Stupid question, why do you want monitor so many keys?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Well, with a JTextComponent I assume all these keys are defined by default. You press a key, and a letter comes up in the editor. 

I foresee in the near future I'll have to support KeyBindings, because to be honest, there are key combinations that I can try to mimic the inner workings of using the KeyListener or KeyAdapter classes (KeyEvent.getKeyChar() and what not), but I don't get very far when trying to add symbols to the mix too.  You somehow have to implicitly know what these keys combos are. What if the user's keyboard is laid out differently?

Comment: Text components are a different best, they are likely using a `KeyListener` to perform the majority of their work, things like HOME, END, PAGE-UP/DOWN etc are bound via key bindings

Comment: @MadProgrammer I wonder how the API of 'TextComponent' did it then. It would be interesting to know how this process is carried out in TextComponents for sure. In either case, I want to pick a place using the mouse click anywhere on the white background to specify where text should be drawn, so I can’t use 'TextComponent'.

Comment: Take a look at the source code, it's in the src.zip in the JDK directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested and tested, and finally found a solution. There are two ways to solve this problem for those interested. I won't go into the way that involved searching through API of TextComponent to discover how it was done there. That was very difficult for me to try to implement myself, and I eventually had to go another route.

I resorted to mapping characters and virtual keys to Actions.

This is what I was looking for: a simple way to loop through characters of interest, and thus save code and complexity in simply mapping keystrokes to actions: If you're not concerned with capturing some key I have listed below *simply remove the character or virtual key from the proper array.* You can even add new characters

First instantiate a JComponent (I used a JFrame called mainPane in this example). I want to capture all keystrokes inputted into the *frame*, so I used JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW.

note the *static* import of KeyEvent constants in the code below.

```
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;

mainPane.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
JRootPane rootPane = mainPane.getRootPane();
InputMap theWIMap = rootPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
ActionMap theAMap = rootPane.getActionMap();
```

Then you can add code that captures letter keystrokes...

```
for(char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
    // upper case
    KeyStroke capital = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("typed " + c);
    theWIMap.put(capital, Character.toString(c));
    theAMap.put(Character.toString(c), new KeyAction(c));

    // lower case
    KeyStroke little = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("typed " + Character.toLowerCase(c));
    theWIMap.put(little, Character.toString(Character.toLowerCase(c)));
    theAMap.put(Character.toString(Character.toLowerCase(c)), new KeyAction(Character.toLowerCase(c)));
}
```

... then write code to capture the typing of *common symbols* on many keyboards (the ones you can see by looking down at the typeface on the keys on your keyboard. I have them listed here in order of their "VK constant values" as specified in [Java API SE 7: Constant Field Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED). (?, %, ~, and | have no VK constants).

```
int[][] characters = new int[][] {
                {'?', '%', '~', '|'},
                {' ', ',', '-', '.', '/'},
                {';', '=', '[', '\\', ']'}, 
                {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'},
                {'*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', '&', '*', '\"', '<', '>', '{', '}', '`', '\''},
                {'@', ':', '^', '$', '!', '(', '#', '+', ')', '_'}
                // if you're so inclined: add even more rows to the bottom
                ,{'¡', '€', '\u02ff'}
};

for(int[] range : characters) 
    for(int i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
        char charForKey = (char)range[i];
        KeyStroke keyboardKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(charForKey);
        theWIMap.put(keyboardKey, charForKey);
        theAMap.put(charForKey, new KeyAction(charForKey));
    }
```

... and finally code to handle the typing of command keys commonly found on lots of keyboards out there.

```
    int[][] commands = new int[][] {
        {VK_BACK_SPACE, VK_ENTER, VK_ESCAPE},
        {VK_PAGE_UP, VK_PAGE_DOWN, VK_END, VK_HOME}, 
        {VK_LEFT, VK_UP, VK_RIGHT, VK_DOWN,  VK_DELETE},
        {VK_KP_UP, VK_KP_DOWN, VK_KP_LEFT, VK_KP_RIGHT},
    };
    for(int[] range : commands)
        for(int i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
            KeyStroke keyboardKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(range[i], 0);
            String commandForKey = KeyEvent.getKeyText(range[i]).toLowerCase();
            theWIMap.put(keyboardKey, commandForKey);
            theAMap.put(commandForKey, new KeyAction(commandForKey));
        }

    theWIMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed " + "TAB"), "tab");
    theAMap.put("tab", new KeyAction("tab"));

    theWIMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift pressed " + "TAB"), "shift tab");
    theAMap.put("shift tab", new KeyAction("shift tab"));
```

Now add in this action code here (ignoring the part about the editor: that's the part that calls my controller):

```
public class KeyAction extends AbstractAction
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public char theLetter;
    public String theCommand;
    public enum KeyType {CHARACTER_ENTRY, KEYSTROKE_COMMAND};
    public final KeyType actionType;

    public KeyAction(char letter)
    {
        theLetter = letter;
        actionType = KeyType.CHARACTER_ENTRY;
    }

    public KeyAction(String command)
    {
        theCommand = command;
        actionType = KeyType.KEYSTROKE_COMMAND;
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        if(actionType == KeyType.CHARACTER_ENTRY) {
            System.out.print(theLetter);
            editor.receiveKey(theLetter);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\n" + theCommand);
            editor.receiveCommand(theCommand);
        }

    }
}
```

And upon opening your application's GUI window, after typing something like this: "I love potato salad. [ENTER] Donate $10.00 now![TAB][SHIFT TAB]"
You should see something similar to this in your terminal.

```
I love potato salad.
enter
Donate $10.00 now!
tab

shift tab
```

Comment: I just thought I'd point out. Two of the characters in my commonly used symbols "char map" (actually a 2D char array) are not ASCII. They are ```"¡" (INVERTED_EXCLAMATION_MARK)``` and ```"€" (EURO_SIGN)```. Attempting to save these characters might throw some editors off. Try using ```'\u00a1'``` and ```'\u20ac'``` to mitigate this.

Answer (score 1):

Most part of the keys and special characters are present in the [KeyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) class. As for the others characters you can obtain the value for the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) table by casting the char as int.

When you're talking about the ActionMap needing to use WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW, it seems to me that you aren't using the [MVC model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), you should consider it.

Comment: To be honest my earlier comment (regarding referencing what "most part" was - now deleted) was a bit over the top.

Comment: @JonAarLivernois well...I have to say, seven years later, no problem buddy. Almost every comment in SO has that razor edge.